# What is the best way to count the number of child objects in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base {
   has_many :bars
}

foo = Foo.find(1)
foo.bars.count
```

Is this the best way to count the number of bars or is there an efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model is completely normalized then this will be the most efficent way.

If you need to do this a lot, you can cache the `bars` count on the `Foo` table.

[Railscast Episode 23](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) covers counter cache, this information is still correct an relevant in the current Rails version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the most efficient way as ActiveRecord converts it to an appropiate SELECT COUNT(*) SQL sentence, which is much more efficient than loading all the records data and count them in an array.